# Call viewmodel method after control id is generated using attr binding

Tags: knockout.js

I have to call a viewmodel method after controls id are generated dynamically attr binding.

Below is my html code

```
 <div data-bind="attr: {id: 'bookScreen_' + bookId }">
 </div>
```

Once control id is generated i want to call a method to where i am doing some work using $(id) selector.

How do i call a viewmodel method once id gets generated for div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule is:

Whenever you want to touch the DOM,

1. Try to do as much as possible via knockout's default bindings. Most event handling can be done by using the `event` or `click` binding. Values can be linked to your viewmodel with the `value` or `textInput` bindings. Styles can be applied with `css`.
2. If there's no default binding, [create a custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).

Some default bindings have an `afterRender` option in which you can specify a callback method that will be passed the element to which bindings have been applied (for example, the `foreach` binding). However, these methods are meant to be used for animations/transitions; changing the DOM isn't recommended.

An example of a custom binding with an `init` method:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.logIDAfterBind = {
  init: function(element) {
    console.log(element.id);
  }
};
```

With the HTML:

```
<div data-bind="attr: {id: 'bookScreen_' + bookId }, logIDAfterBind"></div>
```

**Edit after question in the comments:**

> How do I pass a constant to my custom binding handler?

The `init` method's signature is actually a lot more versatile than I showed in my simplified example. You can pass a value (any valid javascript actually) to a binding using `bindingKey: bindingValue`. For example:

```
<div data-bind="attr: {id: 'bookScreen_' + bookId }, logIDAfterBind: 'a_constant_string'"></div>
```

This value is wrapped in a function and accessible via the second parameter of `init`:

```
init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
  var myConstant = valueAccessor(); // Will be "a_constant_string"
}
```

In bindings that support both observable and other values, you'll often see `ko.unwrap` being used.

```
// Gets the value from the binding; if it's an observable, 
// it "gets" the inner value
var bindingValue = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
```

Comment: Very good solution, i want to pass a value from html suppose i want to pass constant 50 along with element to view model how do i do that?

Comment: I've edited my original answer to include an answer to your question.

Comment: Thnak you i figured it out :)